Using Excel, return 1 for all values >0 WITHOUT using an IF
Working on a covering problem using solver in Excel.  I have a matrix of adjacent cells, and a set of binary decision variables.  I can use sumproduct() across the decision variables and each row of the adjacency matrix to tell me whether a cell is covered by a particular solution.  If I have a constraint on the number of decision variables that can be 1, and I want to maximize the number of covered cells, I need to count how many of those sumproducts return a value >0.  Simple answer would be =IF(<address> > 1, 1, 0) and then sum those up, but solver tells me that anything with IF in it doesn't meet linearity conditions.  I also tried using -- in front of a logical test as shown below and I get the same error...


Any suggestions?

Roughly:

Make the items in column N for covered into binary variables, along with the other declarations you have made.
Add the constraint that those variables in the column are LTE (<=) to the adjacent values in column M.

That's the linearization... for maximizing the sum of "covered"
N    M
0 <= 0
1 <= 1
1 <= 4
1 <= 3
...

If it gets much more complicated, I'd switch to a "real" linear programming framework.  ;)

That makes sense...never would have thought of adding additional decision variables.  Thanks!
